# Error en syntax

Tags: php, html

no soy muy buena programando y recién comienzo. Mi sitio me está dando este error de syntax y no entiendo que puede ser. Alguien me puede explicar a que se debe este error y como podre solucionarlo. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que lo mejor seria que compartas parte del código, para tener contexto para poder ayudare de una mejor manera

Comment: Pero es que no se de donde es el error, desde ayer algunos botones de mi sitio no funcionan al hacer clic. Hay algo que cambio y esta afectando al sitio, y no se que es.

Comment: Si el código fuente del sitio no ha cambiado puede deberse a una actualización en el servidor. Revisa si en el servidor cambió algo como la versión de php, node o las librerías que usas (el sdk de agora.js). Por lo que entiendo, agora tiene su propio canal de soporte.

Comment: Gracias Juan Carlos, ya estoy averiguando al proveedor de hosting y les cuento. Saludos!